# Infinte scroll at the place of panignation in vue3 with element plus

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, element-plus

I am trying to make my grid scrollable infinitely like right now i am using el-pagination for loading new data after a finite chunk of data now i don't want to use that i want to make it scrollable infintely.

I have tried applying  v-infinite-scroll to my grid but as it is a table i have to use this with el-table so it is possible or not?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.